# File Overwrite when Unzipping file from VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, shell, zip, unzip

Need a little help with working with ZIP files, I've made a autopupdate application for my main app it works fine and downloads the Zip from the server and I am able to extract it completely, but problem is if the files are already there and if i try to unzip it again it shows option of Replacing i want to avoid that option and just replace it without giving alert. Please do let me know how can i can i do it.

The code for Unzipping is as follow :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim shObj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"))
    Dim output As Object = shObj.namespace((Application.StartupPath))
    Dim input As Object = shObj.NameSpace((Application.StartupPath + "\temp.zip"))
    output.CopyHere((input.items), 4)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using ZipFile class?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

It has been a while since I used it but as far as I remember it replaces the old files with the extracted ones.

Comment: It is available in FW4.5 not in 4

Comment: Found the Solution as "output.CopyHere((input.items), 16)" and it replaced without giving warning messages.

Comment: Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Infirazor : Actually you can use the `ZipFile` class in .NET 4.0. You just gotta reference the dll `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compr‌​‌​ession.FileSystem\‌​v4‌​.0_4.0.0.0__b77a‌​5c56‌​1934e089\Syste‌​m.IO.C‌​ompression.F‌​ileSyste‌​m.dll`.